# SCM management of AppFabric Cache Cluster

Tags: caching, appfabric

I'm working on building out a standard set of configurations for our cache clusters within App Fabric.  My goal is to have a repeatable cache settings configuration when we load up a new environment (so server names are different, number of hosts, and other environmental factors).

My initial pass was to utilize the XML available from Export-CacheClusterConfig and simply change server names and size attributes in the <hosts> section, but I'm not sure what else is automatically registered with those values (the hostId parameter, for example).

My next approach that I've considered is a PowerShell script to simply build up the various caches with the correct parameters passed in that would simply run as a post-deploy step.

Anyone else have experience with **repeatable** AppFabric cache cluster deployments?

Comment: Which bit are you wanting to make repeatable -  the installation, or the creation of caches after installation?

Comment: The creation of the caches afterwards. The installation of AppFabric turns out to be surprisingly easy - setup /install CachingService CacheClient CacheAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying both, the more successful option seems to be a combination of two factors. Management of the Cache Cluster (host information) is primarily an operations concern and is managed best by the operations team (i.e. those guys that read Server Fault).  Since this information is stored in the configuration as well (and would require an XML file obtained from Export-CacheClusterConfig for each environment) it's best left to the operations team on how they want to manage it.  Importing the wrong file (with the incorrect host information) has led to a number of issues.

So, we're left with PowerShell scripts.  Here's a sample that I have. It could be cleaned up (check for Cache existence first) but you get the general idea. It's also much easier to store in source control (as it's just one file).

```
New-Cache -CacheName CRMTickets -Eviction None -Expirable false -NotificationsEnabled true
New-Cache -CacheName ConsultantCache -Eviction Lru -Expirable true -TimeToLive 60
New-Cache -CacheName WorkitemCache -Eviction None -Expirable true -TimeToLive 60
```